# Trying to do an upsert with a $push in the most efficient manner using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a search query, that if it finds a match, I would like to push onto its 'vals' array, if it does not find a match then I would like to do an insert with the search query along with the newVals array

```
findDict = {a: 100, b: 250, c: 110}
newVals = [{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 4, y:7]}

collection.update(findDict,{'$push': {'vals': newVals}}, upsert = True)
```

In this example above, if a match was found for findDict, then newVals would be pushed onto the existing vals array for the matching record.

If no match is found, I would like it to create a new record that looks like this:

```
{a: 100, b: 250, c: 110, vals: [{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 4, y:7]}
```

I have to do this several million times, so I'm hoping to do it in the  most optimal way. I also have many threads coming in and doing this at once so have to worry about concurrency. The update statement posted above almost seems to work, but it creates an entry like this for some reason if no match is found:

```
{a: 100, b: 250, c: 110, vals: [ [ {x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 4, y:7 ] ]}
```

note the array inside the array...

I currently have a unique combined index on a,b, and c. This can be changed if it will help somehow. I think I could do an update with upsert set to False, followed by an insert which will fail if the unique index exists... but it seems I would be doing each search twice in that case and killing my efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `$push` with `$each`?

```
collection.update(
    findDict,
    {'$push': {'vals': {'$each': newVals}}},
    upsert = True
)
```